# objective C - error message in main- Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, sigabrt

here is my main :

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   #import "SimpleAppAppDelegate.h"
  #import "NewsFeed.h"
   #import "SimpleAppViewController.h"


        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
        @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([SimpleAppAppDelegate                              
    class]));    
    }
    }
```

here is the error message it displays in command :

```
NewsFeedAppTylerCrady[3837:f803]  
2012-10-11 11:15:21.226 NewsFeedAppTylerCrady[3837:f803] Processing Item: 
2012-10-11 11:15:21.227 NewsFeedAppTylerCrady[3837:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13bc052 0x154dd0a 0x1364a78 0x13649e9 0x1389394 0x330f 0x30e8 0x2da8 0x2012 0xd964e 0x39a73 0x39ce2 0x39ea8 0x40d9a 0x11be6 0x128a6 0x21743 0x221f8 0x15aa9 0x12a6fa9 0x13901c5 0x12f5022 0x12f390a 0x12f2db4 0x12f2ccb 0x122a7 0x13a9b 0x3ad8 0x1c35)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

The only methods I have which corresponds to this message are :

```
       -(NSString *) getTitleFromItem:(NSString *)item {
           NSRange titleOpen = [item rangeOfString:@"<title>"];
           NSRange titleClose = [item rangeOfString:@"</title>"];
           NSRange titleRange;
             titleRange.location = titleOpen.location+titleOpen.length;
       titleRange.length = titleClose.location - titleRange.location;
           return [item substringWithRange:titleRange];
       }

      -(NSString *) getDescriptionFromItem:(NSString *)item {
         NSRange descOpen = [item rangeOfString:@"<description>"];
          NSRange descClose = [item rangeOfString:@"</description>"];
          if(descOpen.location==NSNotFound)
              return @"No description available...";
         NSRange descRange;
         descRange.location = descOpen.location + descOpen.length;
          descRange.length = descClose.location - descRange.location;
          return [item substringWithRange:descRange];
      }
```

Comment: And your questions is? First of all, from stack trace, you can get exact file & line number where this happened. So, find the exact place and check lines around. Also you do use `rangeOfString:` and you're not checking results. What if `</title>` doesn't exist?

Comment: @user1071136 Nope, see exception, `substringWithRange:` throws `Range or index out of bounds`. So, check range you're passing to `substringWithRange:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your stack trace:

> ...reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Take a look at the `titleRange` and `descRange`, look like they may be out of range of your string.

Answer (score 2):

Add a check inside both your functions

```
     -(NSString *) getTitleFromItem:(NSString *)item {
           NSRange titleOpen = [item rangeOfString:@"<title>"];
           NSRange titleClose = [item rangeOfString:@"</title>"];
           NSRange titleRange;
           titleRange.location = titleOpen.location+titleOpen.length;
           titleRange.length = titleClose.location - titleRange.location;
           if(titleRange.length <= item.length) // Check
                return [item substringWithRange:titleRange];
           else 
                return nil;
       }
```

Same for the other one.